# While testing for Rotating secret through lambda function

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

this is my lambda function (https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRotationTemplate/lambda_function.py)
when i am testing

```
{"arn":"writing arn from secret",
"token":"any random 32 digit number",
"step":"testsecret"}
```

giving error

```
  "errorMessage": "'SecretId'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "requestId": "########",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 24, in lambda_handler\n    arn = event['SecretId']\n"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function expects `'SecretId' in the event`, but your current `event` does not have it:

```
{"arn":"writing arn from secret",
"token":"any random 32 digit number",
"step":"testsecret"}
```

Guess that `arn` should be `SecretId`:

```
{"SecretId":"writing arn from secret",
"token":"any random 32 digit number",
"step":"testsecret"}
```

You will probably have other similar errors which you have to fix in the same way.

Comment: after your above mentioned issues it's giving errors again                                                                                    "errorMessage": "'SECRETS_MANAGER_ENDPOINT'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "requestId": "########",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 29, in lambda_handler\n    service_client = boto3.client('secretsmanager', endpoint_url=os.environ['SECRETS_MANAGER_ENDPOINT'])\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/os.py\", line 679, in __getitem__\n    raise KeyError(key) from None\n"
  ]

Comment: @Gulshan This is a new error, thus new question should be asked.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen due to three reasons:

1. The existing password in secrets manager does not match with DB Password.(when lambda function tries to authenticate database it should match with existing password so that it could authenticate and update password). you can find the cloudwatch logs as follows:

> [ERROR]   2022-03-03T12:05:24.178Z    1a39a205-36f5-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXX setSecret: Unable to log into database with previous, current, or pending secret of secret arn arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXX:secret:XYZXXXXXXXXXXXXX

2. DB security group should allow lambda fn to access DB instance(create a ingbound rule with lambda sg as source and DB port)
3. verify you have connectivity to secretsmanager api (your NAT gateway should have access to secrets manager api endpoint) and endpoint with service name **com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.secretsmanager** / **endpoint type Interface**
   also verify region in which lambda fn is executed.

Comment: Point 2 helped me identify my issue. Thanks so much!